# How do I translate a specific force layout d3.js node to a specific position?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I have a force layout that has a primary node centered on the screen (fixed position) surrounded by nodes that float around it (not fixed).

example:

[image]

When I click one of the nodes floating around the primary node, I want the clicked node to become the new primary node. I want to animate the clicked node to the center of the page and fix its position there.

I can center the node without an animation like this on click:

```
force.stop();

d3.select("[title='" + nodeName + "']")
    .classed("fixed", function(d) { return d.fixed = true })
    .attr("transform", "translate("+ (width / 2) +","+ (height / 2) +")")
    .attr("cx",(width / 2))
    .attr("cy",(height / 2));
```

but as soon as the force layout starts again, the node returns to its position prior to being centered.

Is there a way to animate a node to a specific coordinate on click?

Comment: You need to set the node data's `x` and `y` (and probably `px` and `py`) attributes accordingly and `fixed` to true.

Comment: Or you can make the existing code that normally renders the force layout "decide" to position the node differently if its datum, `d` has a property `fixed` set to true. (Of course you'll also need to set that property to `true` when a node is clicked).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff any ideas on how I could animate the transform if I edit the node data's x and y?

Comment: You could do that with a transition using a custom tween function that sets the properties.